# Slice/Map Ordered Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

I am writing a "Punch Clock" application for my office.. I am working on the controller for the "TIme Card" view which should list a users punches for a given week, and total DAILY then add the TOTAL for the week. I have figured out how to get the time diff between all of the punches with slice/map, my issue is that when I try to do this on the ordered hash (grouped by days) I get undefined method `created_at' for #, I know I must be missing some syntax somewhere, your help is greatly appreciated...

Here is my controller...

Note that if i call @in_out_lenghts on @punches, this works and gives me the total for the week, but @punches_days gives me an error, therefore I can not keep a running tally....

```
  def mytimecard
       @week = params[:week].to_s
      if @week == "lastweek"
       @punches = Punch.lastweek.where("user_id = ?",  params[:user])
      else 
        @punches = Punch.thisweek.where("user_id = ?",  params[:user])
      end

       @punches_days = @punches.group_by { |t| t.created_at.beginning_of_day}
      if @punches.count%2 == 0
       @in_out_lengths = @punches_days.each_slice(2).map { |a|(a[1].created_at).round(15.minutes) - (a[0].created_at).round(15.minutes) }
       @total          = ((@in_out_lengths.inject(:+))/60/60)
      else
        @total = "Can Not Calculate, Odd Number of Punches"
      end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # timecard.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @punches }
    end
  end
```

Comment: is there no line-number in your error? i think that group by creates another array in your punches-array. have a look at the docs: http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/group_by

Answer (score 0):

group_by will return a hash of days and punches.

```
{ :day_1 => [ :punch1, :punch2], :day_2 => [ :punch3, :punch4, :punch5 ] }
```

doing an each_slice and a map will result in some sort of array, but probably not what you meant.

You may have meant to count the number of punches and call something like this

```
Punch.lastweek.where("user_id = ?",  params[:user]).group('date(created_at)')
```

This would have resulted in the date => punches_count format, at least with mysql.